# when snackbar is being displayed on screen and at the same time if back button is pressed, it throws error in console in flutter / dart

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

when snackbar is being displayed on screen and at the same time if back button is pressed, it throws error in console in flutter / dart

I have removed snackbar by using

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
    return true;
  },
child: Scaffold(...
```

but it is also not working.

error log is as:

```
E/flutter (13058): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter (13058): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter (13058): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It would be great if you can include the logs too or console output in this case

Comment: Do you have nested Scaffolds?

Comment: @gtxtreme I have added error logs / console output in my question. Kindly check and suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: @quoci No, I am 100% sure, not using nested Scaffolds. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your logs, this issue is because the Context is not being passed to the `WillPopScope` widget correctly because it is disposed off

What you can do is

Declare a global variable

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

Then register this `_scaffoldKey` on your `Scaffold` like so

```
 @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       key: _scaffoldKey,
       ...
```

Now whenever you need the access to this context you can use `_scaffoldKey.currentContext` such as in the `ScaffoldMessenger.of`.. part

This should fix your issue